# Taylor expansion of Frobenius Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

I have the following function

$||{\bf A} - {\bf BC}||^2_F$,

where ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, ${\bf B} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times k}$, and ${\bf C} \in \mathbb{C}^{k \times n}$, which is a convex function w.r.t ${\bf B}$. I am looking for taylor expansion of the function w.r.t ${\bf B}$, so that I can write it in the following form:

$f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^H (y - x)$.

Can someone kindly suggest me how to proceed for it?

Comment: See Equation (132) of https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: I get the derivative of the norm. But the derivative will be in matrix form. So how can I get the scalar inner product between derivative and the term as in single variable / vector case.

Comment: For instance, for complex-valued the first order convexity condition can be found here in Appendix C of this book https://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/MAL-051

Comment: Can you kindly comment on the second-order conditions?

Comment: Double post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311878/second-order-taylor-expansion-of-frobenius-norm/3312211#3312211

Comment: Yes sorry for the double post. This post was supposed to be only for convexity condition. I will soon close this post.