# First order Taylor expansion of Frobenius norm

Tags: taylor-expansion, normed-spaces

I need a first-order expansion of the expression $$\|A + \epsilon B\|_F$$ where $A, B$ are symmetric real matrices, and $\epsilon$ is a small number. $A$ is full-rank, for $B$ I would have to check. How can this be computed? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311878/second-order-taylor-expansion-of-frobenius-norm) question/answer may be related, but is currently too complicated for me to understand